# select range of rows of dataframe by business day(python)

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atsPP.png)

Hi, everyone!! Please see this picture and let me know how to select range of rows of dataframe by business day. And please write down codes here.

Comment: Please add some data to your question

Comment: Hi, Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Please explain what you have tried, and what is not working for you. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you have dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "WTI": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    "Brent": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]   
}, index=["2008-01-01", "2008-01-02", "2008-01-03", "2008-01-04", "2008-01-05", "2008-01-06"])

df

# output
    WTI Brent
2008-01-01  1   1
2008-01-02  2   2
2008-01-03  3   3
2008-01-04  4   4
2008-01-05  5   5
2008-01-06  6   6
```

First change date typa of index as datetime:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

And next you can filter it as you want:

```
df[df.index.day_of_week.isin([1, 2, 3, 4])]

# output
    WTI Brent
2008-01-01  0.00    0.00
2008-01-02  99.64   97.01
2008-01-03  99.17   98.45
2008-01-04  1.00    5.00


df[df.index.day_name().isin(["Friday"])]

# output

WTI Brent
2008-01-04  4   4
```

If index is of type pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex you have many possibilities to filter it.
Check doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html

Comment: thanks for your comment. ^^
Your comment can delete weekends. And..can national holidays be deleted??

Comment: Not in this easy way. Pandas has module `pandas.tseries.holiday` - there you can for example do: `from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar calendar().holidays(start="2008-01-01", end="2008-12-31")`

Comment: Thanks!! Your comments are very helpful to me! I appreciate again!!!